# Find a solution of $x\frac{dy}{dx} = y^2 -y$ that passes through the points (1/2, 1/2)

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I do not understand how my instructor simplified the part marked with red circle.
Did he make a mistake? Could anyone help me out here.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nope, he is right

$\frac{1}{y-1}-\frac{1}{y}=\frac{y-(y-1)}{y(y-1)}=\frac{1}{y(y-1)}$

Answer (score 5):

(S)he is right. Note that if you set: $$\frac{1}{y(y-1)}=\frac{A}{y-1}+\frac{B}{y}$$ for some proper values of $A$ and $B$ so you'll have:
$$\frac{1}{y(y-1)}=\frac{(A+B)y-B}{y(y-1)}\longrightarrow A+B=0,~~B=-1$$

Comment: +1, B.S.! Good to see you here!